# Voice channel doesn't get deleted after timeout. Discord.JS 12

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, voice

So I'm currently making final changes in order to update my bot from discord.js 11.4 to 12.

However, I've ran on another issue with private channels, not getting deleted after a certain amount of time.
I tried changing voiceChannel into voice.channel, but it did not work unfortunatelly.

Here's my code:

```
        bot.on("voiceStateUpdate", oldMember => {
            deleteEmptyChannelAfterDelay(oldMember.voiceChannel);
        });
    
        function deleteEmptyChannelAfterDelay(voiceChannel, delayMS = 5000){
            if(!voiceChannel) return; 
            if(voiceChannel.members.first()) return;
            if(!voiceChannel.health) voiceChannel.health = 0;
            voiceChannel.health += 1;
            setTimeout(function(){  //queue channel for deletion and wait
                if(!voiceChannel) return;
                if(voiceChannel.members.first()) return;
                voiceChannel.health -= 1;
                if(voiceChannel.health > 0) return;
                if(!voiceChannel.name.includes('\'s Room')) return;
                voiceChannel.delete()   //delete channel
                    .catch(error => console.log(error));
            }, delayMS);
        }
```

I tried looking for help on djs guides and/or forums, but couldn't find anything, so I'd really appriciate any help possible! Thank you.

Comment: Try changing your parameters to `(oldMember.voiceChannel, 5000)` and have the function receive `(voiceChannel, delayMS)`

Comment: Didn't change anything, unfortunately, :/ The channel stays after leaving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DiscordJS V12, the [`voiceStateUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate) event got changed. Instead of passing the paramters `oldMember` and `newMember`, it now passes `oldState` and `newState` which are instances of [VoiceState](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState). To get the channel the `voiceStateUpdate` got triggered on, you no longer call `member.voiceChannel`, but now call [`VoiceState.channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=channel).

So to make your code work, you have to change your event callback to the following:

```js
bot.on("voiceStateUpdate", oldState => {
    deleteEmptyChannelAfterDelay(oldState.channel);
});
```

Comment: I honestly didn't think about this, rookie mistake hah. Thank you very much for your help!